# Umbraco 4.9.0 usercontrol error

Tags: user-controls, umbraco, asp.net-controls

I'm getting the following error in my usercontrol properties:

```
Error reading usercontrols/BrandHub/emintRegister.ascx

The following list shows the Public Properties from the Control. By checking the Properties and click the "Save Properties" button at the bottom, umbraco will create the corresponding Macro Elements.

System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'umbraco.emintControls.usercontrols.BrandHub.emintRegister'. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'umbraco.emintControls.usercontrols.BrandHub.emintRegister'. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'umbraco.emintControls.usercontrols.BrandHub.emintRegister'. at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at umbraco.developer.assemblyBrowser.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I've tried "/usercontrols/BrandHub/emintRegister.ascx" but I get the same error.

The following error message is displayed on the web page:

```
Error creating control (/usercontrols/BrandHub/emintRegister.ascx).
Maybe file doesn't exists or the usercontrol has a cache directive, which is not allowed! See the tracestack for more information!
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, I forgot to copy the relevant .dll file to the "bin" folder. Glad it was something simple.

Comment: you only need to copy the .dll file no need of copying .pdb file to the bin folder

Comment: lol... i did the same thing, forgot to upload DLL into bin folder, thanks for posting.